# How can I insert a tag <br> into another tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put a `<br>` tag in the end of every `<text></text>` tag. I tried using

```js
var para = document.createElement("br");
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("text");
element.appendChild(para);
```

but i think i can't use the `element.appendChild` for more than 1 tag. Am I right?

Comment: You're right...you must iterate over the nodeList and call appendChild for each single node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"...but i think i can't use the element.appendChild for more than 1 tag. Am I right?"*

Right. There are two parts to your question.

First, you need to loop over the collection returned from `getElementsByTagName()`. It does not have the same set of methods and properties that individual elements have.

Second, to insert a `br` element into each `text` element, you need to create a new `br` element each time since a node can only be in one location in the tree at a time.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("text");

// loop over collection
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // append a newly created `br` for each `text`
  elements[i].appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

```html
<text>foo</text>
<text>bar</text>
```